# Populating display iteration table through AJAX Get

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

There is a View table that displays static elements of a List of type Model for a specific day when the user chooses that day, or displays nothing when a Model is empty.  I've changed the values of single unique fields before, but never fields of a Model List.  In searching SO, I haven't found a question address this exact situation, but some related questions suggest using serialize.  I've tried referencing the List name and populating it with/setting it equal to the returned data, to no avail.  Also, there are no errors through the ActionResult, so the problem probably lies in the AJAX assigning the return values to the List fields.  Is there any way to do this?

HTML:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-8">
        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.PriceDate, "Pricing Date")
        @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.PriceDate, Model.PricingDates, "--New Pricing--")
    </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
<table id="dt_terms" class="table table-striped">
    <tbody>
        <tr><th></th><th class="text-center">ID</th><th class="text-center">Price</th><th class="text-center">Adder Fee</th></tr>
        @if (Model.Prices.Any()) //NEEDS POPULATING!
        {
            for (var i = 0; i < 100; i++)
            {
                <tr>
                    <td><input type="submit" class="btn btn-info" id="priceToOffer" value="Add To Offers"></td>
                    <td class="text-center">@Html.DisplayFor(m => m.Prices[i].ID)</td>
                    <td class="text-center">@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Prices[i].Price, new { @class = "form-control", data_parsley_required = "true" })</td>
                    <td class="text-center">@Html.DisplayFor(m => m.Prices[i].AdderFee)</td>
                </tr>
            }
        }
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Script:

```
$(function () {
    $("#PriceDate").change(function () {
        var $priceTable = $("#dt_terms"),
            $priceValue = $("#PriceDate").val(),
            $pID = { iD: $priceValue };
        if ($(this).val()) {
            //make AJAX call for historical Price data and populate table
            $.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                url: '@Url.Action("GetPrices", "Sales")',
                data: $pID,
                success: function (data) {
                    //Fill data
                    $("#Prices").val(data);
                }
            });
            $priceTable.prop("disabled", true);
        }
        else {
            //clear data
            $("#Prices").val('');
            $priceTable.prop("disabled", false);
        }
    }).change();
});
```

Controller:

```
public ActionResult GetPrices(string iD)
{
    int priceID;
    Int32.TryParse(iD, out priceID);
    //priceID = iD;

    dbEntities db = new dbEntities();
    var selectedPrice = new List<PricesModel>();
    var accountPrices = db.uspGetPrices(priceID);
    foreach (var result in accountPrices)
    {
        var price = new PricesModel
        {
            ID = result.PriceID,
            Price = result.Price,
            AdderFee = result.AdderFee,
        };
        selectedPrice.Add(price);
    }

    return Json(selectedPrice, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

Generated HTML:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-8">
        <label for="PriceDate">Pricing Date</label>
        <select data-val="true" data-val-number="The field PriceDate must be a number." data-val-required="The PriceDate field is required." id="PriceDate" name="PriceDate"><option value="">--New Pricing--</option>
<option value="2">1/4/2016 6:33 PM</option>
</select>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <table id="dt_terms" class="table table-striped">
        <tbody>
            <tr><th></th><th class="text-center">ID</th><th class="text-center">Price</th><th class="text-center">Adder Fee</th></tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is server-side code:

```
@if (Model.Prices.Any()) //NEEDS POPULATING!
```

By the time the page is rendered on the client, that code is long since completed and doesn't execute anymore.  In your AJAX response handler, you need to populate your *client-side* markup with the new data.

What is that data?  Is it a completely new set of data for the table?  In that case, you'd probably just remove the rows from the table and add the new ones.  Something like this:

```
success: function (data) {
    $('#dt_terms tbody tr').remove();

    for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        var row = $('<tr></tr>');

        var idCell = $('<td></td>').append($('<input type="submit" class="btn btn-info" id="priceToOffer" value="Add To Offers">'));
        row.append(idCell);

        // continue for other cells in the table

        $('#dt_terms tbody').append(row);
    }
}
```

The idea being that you'd re-build the markup with the new data, similar to how it was built in the first place by the server-side code.

---

You may be noticing that this duplicates some of the markup structure into the jQuery code.  As the system gets more complex and this continues to happen, you may want to investigate a client-side framework such as AngularJS, which allows you to define views and bind models to them similarly to your server-side code.

In the case of something like that, you'd essentially be doing something *very similar* to what you were originally attempting:

```
$("#Prices").val(data);
```

The syntax would of course be different, and the fundamentals of what's being done would be different (updating an in-memory object instead of a DOM element's value), but *semantically* it seems like it may be more intuitive to how you originally wanted to approach the problem.  It would update an *object* to which the view is bound, and the view would be updated automatically as a result.

In the absence of such a MVC or MVVM framework in your client-side code, you're left with updating the table manually using jQuery.  Which isn't terrible in small cases like this.

Comment: Excellent response, David.  Thank you!  I'll try this and report back.

Comment: David, this works perfectly.  I can't thank you enough!